# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-xkffs1ax/word2vec/

Tags: terminal, python, packages

I'm trying to install word2vec, but I keep on getting this error when I run `pip install word2vec`

```
    Collecting word2vec
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/9c/0cc6019be231950235517c29d2d6a2fca76dfa75ad4162ccce22fb1b4364/word2vec-0.9.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/zj/z4d6pnbj461cs58zwdrqmbc00000gn/T/pip-install-wSs7Uz/word2vec/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ImportError: No module named Cython.Build

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zj/z4d6pnbj461cs58zwdrqmbc00000gn/T/pip-install-wSs7Uz/word2vec/
```

Python and pip version:

```
pip version: 19.0.1

python version: 3.6.5
```

Comment: Ive tried to update my setuptools by running: 
pip install -U setuptools

Everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was some error with my installation of python.

Running the `brew reinstall python` and then running `pip3 install word2vec` seems to have solved the issue.